# Asp.net checkbox - can't get label on same line as checkbox

Tags: html, css, asp.net, checkbox

I have an asp checkbox with a label, but the label is not aligned with the checkbox:

[image]

```
<div class="row checkbox">
    <label for="phcontent_2$cbStayInTouch"><asp:Label id="LabelStayInTouch" runat="server"></asp:Label></label>
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbStayInTouch"/>
</div>
```

I tried using `inline-block` to get the checkbox and label ("Send me emails") next to each other, but it didn't do anything.

I tried wrapping the checkbox in a div and putting `inline-block` on the div and elements inside, like so:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <input id="phcontent_1_cbStayInTouch" type="checkbox" name="phcontent_1$cbStayInTouch" style="display: inline-block;">
    <label for="phcontent_1_cbStayInTouch" style="display: inline-block;">Send me emails</label>
</div>
```

but they still aren't aligned:

[image]

EDIT: It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: How do you want to layout? Could you upload the mock up?

Comment: I added a picture of how it should look to the post

Comment: do you have a width set for your labels?  they should be on the same line unless it has a width that is too wide.  Also on your asp label, you can put `AssociatedControlID="cbStayInTouch"` and then you don't need to hardcode the input id on your outer label

Comment: No. They are both less than half the width of the div they are in.

Comment: Can you add the rendered html and styles to the question as with your current question it is impossible to say what is causing it

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has **form-horizontal** and **form-group** instead of **row**. You can read more [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal).

In addition, you want to use **AssociatedControlID** in ASP.Net.

### Screen Shot

[image]

### ASPX

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="LabelStayInTouch" runat="server" Text="Stay in touch"
            AssociatedControlID="cbStayInTouch" CssClass="col-xs-3 control-label" />
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbStayInTouch"
                Text="Send me emails" CssClass="checkbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text="First Name"
            AssociatedControlID="FirstNameTextBox"
            CssClass="col-xs-3 control-label" />
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameTextBox" runat="server"
                CssClass="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Rendered Output

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="MainContent_cbStayInTouch" id="MainContent_LabelStayInTouch" 
            class="col-xs-3 control-label">Stay in touch</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <span class="checkbox"><input id="MainContent_cbStayInTouch" 
                type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$cbStayInTouch">
                <label for="MainContent_cbStayInTouch">Send me emails</label></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="MainContent_FirstNameTextBox" id="MainContent_FirstNameLabel" 
            class="col-xs-3 control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$FirstNameTextBox" type="text" 
                id="MainContent_FirstNameTextBox" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<div>
 <div style="display: inline-block;">
  <input id="phcontent_1_cbStayInTouch" type="checkbox" name="phcontent_1$cbStayInTouch" >
 </div>    
 <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;">
  <label for="phcontent_1_cbStayInTouch">Send me emails</label>
 </div>
</div>
```